# Logarithms in Calculators?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have no idea how to do logarithms, or even what they are, but our class recently received an extra credit problem pertaining to one. This helps me with *EXACTLY* what I want to do, but I have no idea how to input it into my calculator, where it says "Grab a calculator!" What buttons do I press, what order does it have to go in?

http://www.coolmath.com/algebra/17-exponentials-logarithms/13-radioactive-decay-decibel-levels-02.htm

[image]

Any help?

Comment: @Amzoti When I try to do 2−5.44715, I get "syntax error" on my calculator.

Comment: If you use a subtraction sign rather than a negative sign, you could obtain a syntax error.

Comment: What calculator do you use?

Comment: Maybe you calculatore uses [reverse polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). So add a link to a manual of your calculator if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the calc.exe deployed with the Windows operating system select the scientific calcualtor from the file menue. Then enter:

4 5 * 2 $x^y$ ( $\pm$ 6 . 7 / 1 . 2 3 ) =

Now the following should be displayed

$$1.031467685896385331022583502009$$

To clear the result press

C

But there are calculators that use other syntax.